# I need to add values to an existing list of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition

```
# list of lists (STEP 1)
list0 = ["a", "b", "c"], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [h, i, j]

# input for new values (STEP 2)
k = input("Enter new value: ")
l = input("Enter new value: ")
m = input("Enter new value: ")

# add these values to " list0 " (STEP 3)
list0 += [k, l, m]
```

STEP 3 doesn't work, brings up error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list0 is defined as a tuple (The commas between the lists define it so)

```
list0 = ["a", "b", "c"], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [h, i, j]
```

An option would be simply declare a nested list such as :

```
list0 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
```

And then you can do,

```
k = input("Enter new value: ") # Entered 8
l = input("Enter new value: ") # Entered 9
m = input("Enter new value: ") # Entered 10
```

And finally append it:

```
list0.append([k,l,m])

print list0
o/p: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['h', 'i', 'j'], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared a tuple, not a list.

```
list0 = ["a", "b", "c"], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [h, i, j]
```

equals

```
list0 = (["a", "b", "c"], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [h, i, j])
```

Tuple is immutable.

---

So, please use

```
list0 = [["a", "b", "c"], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [h, i, j]]
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is answered by yuhe ...But here is a short suggestion for you.If you want to add any element in a list use the append function instead.

> list.append(value)